# "Swap out" VS projects in solution maintaining source control

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a solution with several projects. One of these projects is a "Web Site" I need to convert into a "Web App", following the steps outlined at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx

Those steps create the web app as a new project, instead of replacing the old one. Now that I have the Web App working, I need to replace the old one, but I don't want to lose the version control or other TFS things.

So far, I've tried simply replacing the files in the Site project's folder with the files from the App project's folder, but Visual Studio still sees it as a Site. So I edited the .sln file to point to the .csproj, but VS tells me the project "needs to be migrated" (and if I try to do that, it fails).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting project and adding a new one won't lose the version control. When you select Show Deleted Items, you still can view the history of the deleted Web Site project:

[image]